# How can we use row_number() in apache beam sql

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, beam-sql

I tried that but getting following error.
eg:

```
SELECT RELEASE_ORDER_KEY,ORDER_LINE_KEY,ORDER_HEADER_KEY,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ORDER_LINE_KEY ORDER BY RELEASE_ORDER_KEY) row_num FROM OMS_DATALAKE_ORDER_RELEASE_TAX ORDER BY ORDER_LINE_KEY LIMIT 5
```

Error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot translate call ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY $t1 ORDER BY $t0 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)

Comment: did you got any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

BeamSQL does not support ROW_NUMBER() function(at least until 2.15).

Comment: Hi Rui, Is row_number() available now in Beam SQL?

Comment: Not yet so far. There might be a support by this June (someone could start to work on https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-9198)

Comment: Hi Rui, Is row_number() added now in Beam SQL?

Comment: Hi there. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-9198 is being implemented by a GSoC student. row_number might be able to get implemented soon.

Comment: Currently row_number is supported in Beam master branch.

Comment: It is newly merged thus not in a release yet. You will need to wait for 2.24.0 release. This is the PR that adds the support: https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/12375

Comment: Hi Rui, thanks, could you please tentatively provide by what date/month this release may be available?

Comment: probably after 6 weeks.

Comment: No problem. Meanwhile, if possible, please test your usage with Beam main branch and report whatever bugs or missing feature you find. Just in case when you find any bugs in the next release and report, you will need to wait for the next next release.

Comment: Hi Rui, can you please check below issue
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63376231/beam-sql-current-timestamp