# Beam SQL CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Tags: apache-beam, beam-sql

My Unix Spark Server timezone is CDT but when I'm running Beam SQL CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as below it is always coming as UTC. I tried locally also but it is always displaying UTC. I want this to be CDT same as server zone in CURRENT_TIMESTAMP function. Can you please advise fix for this?

```
         PCollection<Row> cnct = testApps
                           .apply(SqlTransform.query("SELECT  current_timestamp as ts "
                                        + "FROM PCOLLECTION"));
```

Comment: You can add transformer right after that that convert from UTC to CDT, or also do it with UDF

Comment: yes for now i did it with udf but wondering this a defect in beam sql which should be fixed, so wanted to inform it to apache beam team.